# Android - RelativeLayout programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a layout pro-grammatically but it's not working.
Here is the XML version, which looks right.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:paddingTop="4dip" 
android:paddingBottom="6dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:text="TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView" />
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

This is the Java version:

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams  lp;

    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    rl.setLayoutParams(lp);

    CheckBox cbox = new CheckBox(this);
    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    cbox.setLayoutParams(lp);

    EditText etext = new EditText(this);
    etext.setText("TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView");
    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE, cbox.getId());
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, cbox.getId());
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, cbox.getId());
    etext.setLayoutParams(lp);

    rl.addView(cbox);
    rl.addView(etext);
    this.setContentView(rl);
```

This is the output:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Might be off-topic, but have you considered using a [CheckedTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html)?

Comment: I didn't know it existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't set an id on the checkbox, so `cbox.getId()` is probably not returning anything sensible. See [the documentation for `setId` here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)).

At any rate, consider using a [CheckedTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html) instead! Think you might need to specify a drawable to use explicitly, however.

Answer (score -1):

In your Java Version you are using EditText instead oft a TextView like you did in xml

Comment: That doesn't make any difference. Same result.